# Angular/TypeScript - http post using a custom class' toString()

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I am using Angular Reactive forms, I am getting `form.value` and sending it to asp.net web-api. The object named `len` in the code snipped below is a custom class that I wrote that is a very simple version of `TimeSpan`.

Here is my request;

```
{
  "id": "a7b06cf9-36a5-4c7a-99e5-8b9661469329",
  "minCapacity": 5,
  "maxCapacity": 10,
  "len": {
    "Days": 0,
    "Hours": 2,
    "Minutes": 0
  },
}
```

By default `.NET TimeSpan` requires an input like this:

> `string.Format("{0}.{1}:{2}:{3}", len.Days, len.Hours, len.Minutes, len.Seconds)`

And otherwise grabs the variable `len` as null.

Therefore, I have implemented an override `toString()` to my custom `TimeSpan` class. Yet when using the HTTP class in my `Typescript` code I still get the object in JSON format.

I have fiddled around SO for a couple hours, as well as google, yet I have failed to find an answer. I am hoping this is not a duplicate

Is there a way to override this at `client side`?

**component.ts**

```
saveItem(model: Room) {
    let selected = this.selected;
    this.roomService.createUpdateRoom(model).subscribe(
        response => {
            Helpers.setLoading(false);
            var result = response as ServiceResult<any>;
            if (result.hasError) {
                this.toaster.error(result.message, 'Error');
            }
            else {
                alert('ok');
                this.viewForm();
            }
        },
        error => {
            this.toaster.error(error.message, 'Error');
        });
}
```

**service.ts**

```
createUpdateRoom(request) {
    return this.post('api/v1.0/room/createupdate', true, request);
}
```

**base.service.ts**

```
post(apiAddress: string, isAuthorizeRequest: boolean, parameter: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.intercept(this.injector.get(AuthHttp).post(this.baseUrl + apiAddress, parameter).map(
            (response) => {
                let data = response.json();
                if (data) {
                    httpSuccess = data;
                }
                return httpSuccess;
            }
        ));
    }
```

**timespan.ts**

```
export class TimeSpan {
day: number = 0;
hour: number = 0;
minute: number = 0;

toTimeString(): string {
    return this.hour +':' + this.minute;
}

toString = (): string => {

    return this.day + ':' + this.toTimeString() + ':00';
}
}
```

**room.ts**

```
export class Room {
    id: string;
    minCapacity: number;
    maxCapacity: number;
    len: TimeSpan;
}
```

Comment: The question lacks the actual client-side code you're describing. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please share client side code to help you

Comment: Yes. Don't describe the code with words, post it instead. The thing you're describing may make sense for you but not for other users. The question should have clear problem statement, otherwise it can be considered off-topic and be closed.

Comment: I read your comment wrong, I am sorry, i thought you wanted server-side code :)

Comment: @HakanMaac Still not really sure what's going on there, code pieces are too scattered. How is saveItem being called? is If you worry about model: Room not being in the shape it should be send to the backend, then use a function to pre-process a model on submit, as the answer suggests. It's not even obvious from the code above that model is really an instance of Room, and len is an instance of TimeSpan. If they originate from form control, model is likely a plain object.

Comment: @estus I am using Angular Reactive forms, I am getting form.value from submit method to saveItem and sending it to asp.net web-api as you see on the second code snippet. I solved it with a workaround as you and nicusor suggested in his answer. I dont really like to use such workarounds in my code, I have to until I get a proper solution.

Comment: This is considered a common solution and not a workaround, because that's how TS works. Hope the answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar problem, when the form-model was different from the data-model on a specific property. What I ended up doing is specifying a pre-processing and post-processing step when converting from the form-model to the data-model and vice-versa. This might not be the best solution but by making it a clear pattern it was easy to manage.

Comment: so is this because I take it straight from Form? does it use toString() method of the object by default?

Comment: It still did not work when I tried to reconstruct the object as `TimeSpan`. So I overwritten the value of `len` with `len.toString()`. I wish there was a way to send the data in string type using class' `toString()` function.

Comment: I think you'll have to implement the conversion yourself. Relying on Angular to do this automatically might be dangerous since boolean values and numbers also have the `toString()` function and can cause problems.

If you're sure that you want this behavior for all the requests you could implement a Http Interceptor which will apply a function to all the request bodies. But still, you should be sure that you want this.

Answer (score 0):

Form group value is a plain object or an array in Angular reactive forms.

There is a misunderstanding that is common among developers with C# or Java background regarding how TypeScript types work, even if the syntax is similar. TypeScript is basically JavaScript (ES.Next) with type checking. TypeScript types affect only type checking on compilation time and don't affect the output that is executed at run time (with the exception of emitted decorator metadata).

`model: Room` doesn't make `model` an *instance* of `Room` class. `Room` class is used as interface, and `saveItem(model: Room) { ... }` type implies that `model` object conforms to `Room` *interface*. Type check will pass if TypeScript considers `model` a plain object that has properties listed in `Room` interface. It will also pass if `model` is `any`. The same applies to type assertions.

In order for a model to be a hierarchy of expected class instances (`Room` and `TimeSpan`), they should be instantiated. The recipe for that is to make a class accept properties on construction:

```
export class TimeSpan {
  ...
  constructor(plainObj: ITimeSpan) {
    this.day = plainObj.day;
    ...
  }
}

export class Room {
  ...
  constructor(plainObj: IRoom) {
    this.len = new TimeSpan(plainObj.len);
    ...
  }
}
```

Where `ITimeSpan` and `IRoom` are interfaces and subsets of `TimeSpan` and `Room` that contain only properties and not methods.

Then `Room` can be instantiated when needed:

```
saveItem(plainModel: IRoom) {
  const model = new Room(plainModel);
  ...
}
```

Unless there are other reason for `Room` and `TimeSpan` to exist except custom `toString` (e.g. to hydrate a form from JSON plain object on edit), they can be considered redundant. Necessary model pre-processing of `plainModel: IRoom` properties (date stringification, etc.) can be performed on form submit instead, e.g. in `processModel` method.